# Python groupby/convert join table to triple nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, nested

From a SQL stored procedure that performs a join on 3 tables I get the data below.

```
    data = [
        {"so_number": "ABC", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 0, "part_number": "XTZ", "ticket_id": 10, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "ABC", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 0, "part_number": "XTZ", "ticket_id": 11, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "ABC", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 1, "part_number": "XTY", "ticket_id": 12, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "DEF", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 3, "part_number": "XTU", "ticket_id": 13, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "DEF", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 3, "part_number": "XTU", "ticket_id": 14, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "DEF", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 3, "part_number": "XTU", "ticket_id": 15, "ticket_month": "JUNE"}]
```

I would like to group the data on so_number and item_id to return a list of dicts like below.

```
[
  {
    "so_number ": "ABC",
    "po_status": "OPEN",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 0,
        "part_number": "XTZ",
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 10,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 11,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "item_id": 1,
        "part_number": "XTY",
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 12,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "so_number ": "DEF",
    "po_status": "OPEN",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 3,
        "part_number": "XTU"
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 13,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 14,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 15,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I wanted to know if there was an efficient way of doing this. I am open to using pandas as well.

I thought about accessing the 3 sql tables through a loop and creating this list of dicts but it will probably not be best practice or efficient.

Comment: Yes you can use pandas to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Given the nested structure, you could use groupby in loops:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = [
        {"so_number": "ABC", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 0, "part_number": "XTZ", "ticket_id": 10, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "ABC", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 0, "part_number": "XTZ", "ticket_id": 11, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "ABC", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 1, "part_number": "XTY", "ticket_id": 12, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "DEF", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 3, "part_number": "XTU", "ticket_id": 13, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "DEF", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 3, "part_number": "XTU", "ticket_id": 14, "ticket_month": "JUNE"},
        {"so_number": "DEF", "po_status": "OPEN", "item_id": 3, "part_number": "XTU", "ticket_id": 15, "ticket_month": "JUNE"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

res = []
for (so, po), dfg1 in df.groupby(["so_number", "po_status"]):
    d1 = {"so_number ": so,
         "po_status": po,
         "line_items": []
        }
    for (iid, pnb), dfg2 in dfg1.groupby(["item_id", "part_number"]):
        d2 = {"item_id": iid,
             "part_number": pnb,
             "tickets": dfg2[["ticket_id", "ticket_month"]].to_dict(orient="records")
            }
        d1["line_items"].append(d2)
    res.append(d1)

print(json.dumps(res, indent=2, default=int))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "so_number ": "ABC",
    "po_status": "OPEN",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 0,
        "part_number": "XTZ",
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 10,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 11,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "item_id": 1,
        "part_number": "XTY",
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 12,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "so_number ": "DEF",
    "po_status": "OPEN",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 3,
        "part_number": "XTU",
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 13,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 14,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 15,
            "ticket_month": "JUNE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Edit following your comment: you will still have to define the grouping keys. But you can do it only once and keep all other keys at the last level:

```
res = []
lvl1 = ["so_number", "po_status"]
lvl2 = ["item_id", "part_number"]
for val1, dfg1 in df.groupby(lvl1):
    d1 = dict(zip(lvl1, val1))
    d1["line_items"]= []
    for val2, dfg2 in dfg1.groupby(lvl2):
        d2 = dict(zip(lvl2, val2))
        d2["tickets"]= dfg2.drop(columns=lvl1+lvl2).to_dict(orient="records")
        d1["line_items"].append(d2)
    res.append(d1)
```

Comment: When looping through the groupby and assiging the keys I see you do it positionally. I will have a ton more keys than what was in the data payload.

Instead of doing for (so, po.........), dfg1 in df.groupby(["so_number", "po_status"]): 
 d1 = {"so_number ": so,
         "po_status": po,

is there a way to find an interable and so I can assign keys easier?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand but I edited my answer. Check it out!